# Where is this statement (or its equivalent) about God's existence found in Samkhya texts?

Tags: identification-request, reference-request, atheism, samkhya

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya#Arguments_against_Ishvara%27s_existence):

> Furthermore, there is no proof of the existence of God. He is not the object of perception, there exists no general proposition that can prove him by inference and the testimony of the Vedas speak of prakṛti as the origin of the world, not God.

Where is this statement (or its equivalent) found in Samkhya texts?

Comment: Alas! We can really hope such good philosophic questions to come more on the site!

Comment: *If the existence of karma is assumed, the proposition of God as a moral governor of the universe is unnecessary.* This was the Buddhist proposition. You cannot prove the existence of gods, rather the nature of the world is simplified by the personification of them in the form of entities. In Vedas, just as *Vayu dev* is the personified form of *air*, *agni dev* as *fire*, and the same for the brahman follows - personification of the whole experience. So, it doesn't *necessarily* need to exist in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above verses are from Sankya Sutras of Kapila. You can refer from here [1](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/kapila/kapila_index.asp) .

> [This objection to the definition of Perception has no force]; because
> it is not proved that there is a Lord (śwara). [And, further,] it is
> not proved that he [the 'Lord,'] exists; because [whoever exists must
> be either free or bound; and], of free and bound, he can be neither
> the one nor the other. (Aph 92-93, Book 1 , Sankya Sutras translated
> by James R. Ballantyne )
>
> It is not established [that there is an eternal Lord]; because there
> is no evidence of it. (Aph 10 Book 5, Sankya Sutras translated by James R.
> Ballantyne).
>
> Commentary by Vijnanabhiksu on the verse : Its establishment, i.e., the establishing
> that there is an eternal Lord. Of the Lord, in the first place, **there
> is not sense-evidence; so that only the evidences of inference and of
> testimony can be offered; and these are inapplicable: such is the
> meaning.**
>
> **There is no inferential proof [of there being a
> Lord];** because there is [here] no [case of invariable] association
> [between a sign and that which it might betoken]. Moreover, there is
> **Scripture for [this world's] being the product of Nature, [not of a
> Lord].** (Aph 10-12, Book 5, Sankya Sutras translated by James R.
> Ballantyne)

Answer (score 0):

Available texts on Samkya darsana , does not recognise , Ishwara to be the cause of the jagat(cosmos). In other words it  does not posit the One purusha(consciousness) to be the jagat karana(author of creation , ..sustenance, dissolution). Nonetheless ,It  postulates aggregation of purushas , where  each purusha is a pure jnana  allies with  prakriti(=uncaused independent eternal seperate entity)  like lame-dumb is said to ve caused the creation.The purpose of the Ally is for the emancipation of individual sadhaka by knowing ones true identity as purusha . (Prati purusha vimokshanartham).It seems to be a bottom up approach, focusing only on how an individual sadhaka would  recognise the antaryamin purusha,

References - Sankhya karika RK mutt - translated by Swami Virupakshananda.

**PANGU ANDHAVAT**

[image: PANGU ANDHAVAT]

[image]

*PS - (afaik)Sankya karika( by Iswara Krishna - disciple lineage of Kapila muni) is the only surviving text of sankya darsana (whose aphorisms are fundamental to other avail. texts on the subject ,say like yukti dipika).The Original teaching by Kapilamuni, isn't still extant for reference.*